# How does one enable FXP in Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5's FTP?

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have opened 2 threads at Microsoft's places already:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f3cfdba6-5b3e-4342-85ef-fd68fb59fef4/enable-fxp-in-server-2012-r2-iis-80-?forum=winserver8gen#a0a5ad52-71e7-4e27-847e-5c810d9d2040

http://forums.iis.net/t/1208163.aspx?IIS+8+0+Enable+FXP+in+IIS+FTP+

But no one seems to be able to help me, or know the answer. As I have mentioned I read the 7.5 documentation but I can't find any options within IIS 8.5.

PASV port range is enabled and the FTP does work. If I try to FXP I get:

```
(17:40:23) [2] 501-Server cannot accept argument.
(17:40:23) [2]  Win32 error:   The parameter is incorrect. 
(17:40:23) [2]  Error details: Client IP on the control channel didn't match the client IP on the data channel.
(17:40:23) [2] 501 End
```

which of course is expected since I haven't enabled FXP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the dataChannelSecurity element under `system.ftpServer/security` node.

On my IIS 8.5, the settings are under `system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/ftpServer/security/dataChannelSecurity`,

so you were looking in the wrong place, the location is the same for IIS 7.5